# How can I set my slider at the bottom of my page?

Tags: html, css

I want to place my slider at the bottom of the page. I have tried using `position: absolute;` and `bottom:0;` but it doesn't work. Please help me the `CSS` so that I can set my Slider to the bottom of the page.

```
.slider {
   margin-left: 15%;
   margin-right: 15%;
   position:absolute;
}
```

I really want this slider just to be in the bottom of page. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @Alfie, can you also include your HTML structure. Absolute positioning will work if the element you're positioning isn't wrapped in another position relative container. I suspect you'll want `<div class="slider">` to be closer to the Body tag. And then you'll introduce a height offset issue. You may want to look into `display: flex` https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing `position:absolute;` to `position:fixed;`

```
.slider {
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-right: 15%;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `bottom:0;`

```
.slider {
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-right: 15%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have to  do is, set `position:absolute;` and `bottom:0;`. If you want some margin bottom set `bottom` to your desired value

```
.slider {
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you want to put the slider on the bottom of the page or the bottom of screen.
But in both case, for clean solution, you have to create an parent tag (with class parent) for slider and set some css for that parent tag:

Case 1, if you want to set the slider to the bottom of the page:

```
.parent {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0px;
}
```

Case 2. if you want to set the slider to the bottom of the screen:

```
.parent {
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 0px;
}
```